# Magento - set default filter in layer

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I need some help with the following issue. I use an attribute in the layered navigation which is connected to stock values. The attribute has two options - In stock and All products (which includes out of stock products as well).

Is there any way I can have the In stock option selected by default when an user enters a category page? This way users would view only products which are in stock, but if they want they can select all products and also view the others.

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check the url after selecting the attribute you want to show in default and pass that url when that category is clicked.

This can be the option.